# Add div before and after a specific string

Tags: php, string

I want to make a function for adding a div around a specific string.

Current (pseudo) code:

```
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla bla GOD";

function addClass($string) {

    if ( // contain word "GOD") {

        return "<div class=mark>GOD</div>";     

    }

}
```

So the result would be:

```
$result = "bla bla bla bla bla bla <div class=mark>GOD</div>";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_replace like this:

[DEMO](https://eval.in/587616)

```
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla bla GOD";

$searchString = "GOD";

echo preg_replace("/\b($searchString)\b/", "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);
```

Results:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla <div class="mark">GOD</div>
```

---

If you need in function:

```
function addClass($string) {
    $searchString = "GOD";
    return preg_replace("/\b($searchString)\b/", "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);
}

echo addClass($string);
```

---

**Update:** *will this work if there are multiple "GOD" string?*

For this `"bla GOD bla GODisGreat bla bla GOD"`

Result is:

```
bla <div class=mark>GOD</div> bla GODisGreat bla bla <div class=mark>GOD</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a regex to find an exact word. I think this would do it:

```
echo preg_replace('/\bGOD\b/', '<div class="mark">GOD</div>', "bla bla bla bla bla bla GOD");
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/587613
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kU4kA2/1